# error in referencing a project and calling its class

Tags: c#

I am facing the following issue with this piece of code. First of all I have created a project called Generic Lib. Then I create another project called page factory and adding the reference of GenericLib. Hence when I try creating an object of the class from GenericLib it's throwing an error.

```
namespace GenericLib

{
    public class WebDriver
    {

        private static IWebDriver driver;
        public WebDriver(IWebDriver a=null)
        {
            driver = a;
        }
        public IWebDriver Driver
        {
            get { return driver; }
            set { driver = new FirefoxDriver(); }

        }
}
```

Created a reference and trying to access the Driver function in PageFactory by creating an object. Seen with the following error. A field initializer cannot reference the non static field method or property.

```
using GenericLib;
namespace PageFactory
{

    [TestClass]
    public class LoginPage
    {
       public WebDriver web1 = new WebDriver();
       public IWebElement loginSubmitBtn = web1.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""));

        }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

```
using GenericLib;
namespace PageFactory
{

    [TestClass]
    public class LoginPage
    {
       public WebDriver web1;
       public IWebElement loginSubmitBtn;

       [TestInitialize]
       public void TestSetup()
       {
          web1 = new WebDriver();
          loginSubmitBtn = web1.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""));
       } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use one instance variable to initialize another instance variable in this way.  Your example could just as easily be written with strings:

```
public class Class1
{
    public String X = String.Format("{0}", "Hello");
    public String Y = X.Substring(1);  //Error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Namespace.Class1.X'
}
```

The C# language spec actually calls out this type of example in section [10.4.5.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference this in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a simple-name.

Your best bet is to populate the value that depends on another instance variable in the constructor, so back to your example:

```
[TestClass]
public class LoginPage
{
   public WebDriver web1 = new WebDriver();
   public IWebElement loginSubmitBtn;
   public LoginPage() 
   {
        loginSubmitBtn = web1.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize these objects in the constructor of `LoginPage`:

```
[TestClass]
public class LoginPage
{
    public WebDriver web1;
    public IDisposable loginSubmitBtn;

    public LoginPage()
    {
        web1 = new WebDriver();
        loginSubmitBtn = web1.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""));
    }
}
```